# How to pass arguments to a function that itself is passed as a kwarg

Tags: python, function, keyword-argument

In the following example I'm trying to pass arguments to a function that itself has been passed as a kwarg. I have not been successful in passing arguments to the function 'func' from within the class 'TestClass' in the following example:

```
import sys, threading; from threading import Thread

def func(kwargs): 
    print('IN:', sys._getframe(0).f_code.co_name)
    for key, value in kwargs.items() :
        print ('KEY:', key, ', VAL:', value, sep='')

class TestClass(Thread):
    
    def __init__(self, name = sys._getframe(0).f_code.co_name, kwargs = None):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        print('IN:', self.name)
        
    def run(self):
        func = self.kwargs['func']        
        func_kwargs_inner = {'arg_1': 'INNER-1', 'arg_2': 'INNER-2'}        
        func()  # how to pass func_kwargs_inner to func?
        
def main():
    func_kwargs = {'arg_1': 'OUTER-1', 'arg_2': 'OUTER-2'}  # these get passed
#     func_kwargs = {}  # func_kwargs never gets populated
    kwargs = {'func': (lambda: func(func_kwargs))}    
    test = TestClass(name='my-test', kwargs=kwargs)
    test.start()
    print('PROGRAM END')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I try to pass 'func_kwargs_inner' to 'func()', I get syntax errors; if I leave the argument list empty  - as in the example - the result is:

```
IN: my-test
IN: func
KEY:arg_1, VAL:OUTER-1
KEY:arg_2, VAL:OUTER-2
PROGRAM END
```

whereas the required output once I find a way to pass the arguments correctly is:

```
IN: my-test
IN: func
KEY:arg_1, VAL:INNER-1
KEY:arg_2, VAL:INNER-2
PROGRAM END
```

How do I pass 'func_kwargs_inner' to 'func()'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if you do the obvious thing, then it will work, and that your code at present explicitly *avoids* passing the arguments that you want.  Specifically, in your `TestClass.run` you are not passing any arguments to `func` but instead relies on function arguments that are hard-coded into the lambda expression. So change your line:

```
        func()  # how to pass func_kwargs_inner to func?
```

to pass the arguments:

```
        func(func_kwargs_inner)
```

Then in `main`, instead of that `lambda` expression:

```
    kwargs = {'func': (lambda: func(func_kwargs))}
```

simply pass the function object itself:

```
    kwargs = {'func': func}
```

Then you get the expected output:

```
IN: my-test
IN: func
PROGRAM END
KEY:arg_1, VAL:INNER-1
KEY:arg_2, VAL:INNER-2
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using the lambda expression to prevent 'func' from executing immediately in cases where I need to pass a variable number of functions with a variable number of arguments TO the class. In this particular case that's not necessary and I now see that your simpler solution is all that's needed.